# Automate browserstack: Keyboard is not open on iphone web

Tags: selenium, robotframework, browserstack

I am using robot framework, SeleniumLibrary and browserstack for automation. The issue I am having is now that the keyboard for iphone is not open every time I interact with input field. Although, it is working fine in any Android & any browsers.

```
Input Text    xpath=//input[@class='example']    XXX
```

I tried to first click on the input field, then insert the string. But the issue is still occurs. Anyone has any ideas why?
Thank you.

Comment: What did you get as an error message, when it does fail?

Comment: No it doesn't fail the test. No error message. But it doesn't look like real interaction

Comment: Is there any differences between iOS versions, is happening for all 12 / 13 versions example?